# How do I submit a form without refreshing the entire page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I've looked into this some time, and all examples I've found always includes text input fields and php.

I've created a community which has a "Like-button", one click shows a higher number, click again and it drops -1, it works like a charm. But I don't like the refresh part, it messes everything up and starts at the top.

I've tried tons of Ajax/Jquery coding but can't prevent the "reload part".
I don't know if I have any code to post since I never save any of the worthless codes that never works.

However, the form starts like this and includes the "submit-image":

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Like", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null, new { id = "LikeForm" }))
{
...
<input type="image" src="../Images/star.png" name="submit" />
...
}
```

The result is presented in a  nearby.

Everything is sent to the **ActionResult Like()** that saves everything in the database. The result is later presented in the **View**. Nothing unusual about that part I hope.

Once again, I've looked into many examples and none worked for me, my main page for information was at http://api.jquery.com/ and stackoverflow. Nothing gained in this case.

Comment: you are using ajax form so it should not refresh whole page

Comment: If I only had a dollar for every time this question is asked. Have you searched for the answer?

Comment: I've tried all different types of form types. Each result is the same.

EthernalHour, if you read my question you'll see that I've searched. If I remember right using a text-input worked, but I'm not using that.

Answer (score 3):

If your attempted to do it using jQuery before, I expect that your code looked something like this:

```
$('#LikeForm').on('submit', function() {
  // do AJAX stuff here
});
```

This is already close enough, just missing the part where it prevents the form from still being submitted the traditional way. If you still haven't tried so, try doing it like this:

```
$('#LikeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do AJAX stuff here
});
```

What it does is that it prevents the default behavior of the form element (which is, to submit itself with a page reload), and just do the AJAX stuff.

Comment: This is essentially the way to go, but I'd like to add that since it looks like you're using ASP.NET MVC, if you want to go this route, you'll want to remove the "Ajax.BeginForm" and just use "Html.BeginForm" instead.

Comment: I have tried many combinations of the code above, including catching for Form's #id of the #id of the submit-button, I've found many examples from api.jquery.com. However none of them managed to call my actionresult and perform the 'magic'.

Comment: Maybe your AJAX request was just not sent to the correct URL. Did you get the right URL for your actionresult from the form? You can do it inside the event handler like so: `$(this).attr('action')`.

Comment: I have tried this: $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: $form.attr('action')... I believe the URL was right, tried about 3-5 combinations.

Comment: @Varg and what was you script before change? Why not copy and paste it and add e.preventDefault()?